# Why does this intersects function not work?

Tags: java, lwjgl, intersection

This code doesn't show when two rectangles intersects properly:

```
public boolean intersects(Entity other) {
    hitbox.setBounds((int) x, (int) y, (int) width, (int) height);
    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println(y);
    System.out.println(width);
    System.out.println(height);
    boolean a = false;
    Point b = new Point();
    Point c = new Point();
    Point d = new Point();
    Point e = new Point();
    b.setLocation((int)other.getX(), (int)other.getY());
    c.setLocation((int)other.getX() + (int)other.getWidth(), (int)other.getY());
    d.setLocation((int)other.getX() + (int)other.getWidth(), (int)other.getY() + (int)other.getHeight());
    e.setLocation((int)other.getX(), (int)other.getY() + (int)other.getHeight());
    if(hitbox.contains(b)){a = true;}
    if(hitbox.contains(c)){a = true;}
    if(hitbox.contains(d)){a = true;}
    if(hitbox.contains(e)){a = true;}
    return a;
}
```

To begin with it reports rectangles as intersecting when the aren't, then suddenly refuses to accept they intersect at all, even when they do.

Comment: Are you sure the contains function works properly?

Comment: This is one of the less efficient implementation of a rect to rect intersection that I've ever seen: allocating 4 objects, then use setters, then check all 4 points in all cases. This can be improved a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not work because rectangle intersection does not require corners of one rectangle to be inside another rectangle. This could lead to false negatives, i.e. getting a `false` for rectangles that intersect.

[image: Illustration].

Another way of getting a false negative is when two or four corners of your `hitbox` are inside the `other` rectangle: since you are checking it only one way, not the other way, intersections of such kind would go undetected as well.

[image: Hitbox non-symmetry.]

You do not have to use any of the system classes to determine that rectangles intersect. You can do it like this:

```
boolean intersectRect(int x1, int y1, int w1, h1, int x2, int y2, int w2, int h2) {
    return intersectRange(x1, x1+w1, x2, x2+w2)
        && intersectRange(y1, y1+h1, y2, y2+h2);
}
boolean intersectRange(int ax1, int ax2, int bx1, int bx2) {
    return Math.max(ax1, bx1) <= Math.min(ax2, bx2);
}
```

Comment: As I said, it doesn't work at all. I did not plan to make it so that it would ever need to do this.

Comment: @BenHack See the update for another way in which your code could fail.

Comment: Thanks, now it make total sense. Why do I think I have checked something, but never have.

Answer (score 2):

Don't reinvent the wheel:

```
Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(x,y,width,height);
Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(other.getX(),other.getY(),other.getWidth(),other.getHeight());

return r1.intersect(r2);
```

Mind that this requires 2 object allocations, it can be done with no object allocations at all if you mind calculating bounds directly in your code.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I was so sure there was no such function, but obviously I somehow tricked myself. Thanks, though I still maintain that the question is why mine fails.